# How I can listen to all http requests of a webserver with c++?

Tags: c++, http, sockets, networking, port

I have make a lot of researches about this topic, but I don't find an answer, or I find it but don't understand really well.

I'm a beginner with network/programming network, so I need to understand something.

My question :
In my case, I have already an httpserver, running on the port 3000.
I want a c++ program who listen to all http-request that are received by my webserver on the port 3000.

I know that I can't run more than one service who listen on my port 3000. So I have discovered, socket who allow communication in relation client/server, but I don't think it's really appropriate.. Im using tcpdump to already scan http-request from my port 3000, I really would like to understand how to do this with c++.

I hope I've made myself clear.

Thank's !

Comment: The design pattern for such a use case is called "Reactor". Please google for that.

Answer (score 2):

make a c++ program that listens of port 3000, make the server listen on 3001 and have your app forward the requests to port 3001 after it has processed them

```
 tcp->3000->your_app->3001->web_server
```

Comment: Or, you can just use a network sniffing library, like libpcap, and have it watch the webserver's port. You would have to manually parse the traffic to discover each HTTP message, though. But then, you would have to do that anyway if you follow the advice above.